# Replace 4 different characters

Tags: c#, replace

I'm trying to take the user input, E.G. `ATCG` and replace the letters with `TAGC`. These are DNA Complementary Bases. For example, if the user was to enter `ATCGGGC` it would output `TAGCCCG`. I've managed to replace 1 character, but I'm not sure how to get the others to replace.

```
namespace DNA_Replication_EASY
{
    class Program
    {

        static string input1;


        public static string InputBaseWithSpaces()
        {
            return string.Join(" ", input1.ToCharArray());
        }

        public static string OpposingBases()
        {
            string outputBases1 = input1.Replace("A", "T");
            return outputBases1;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please type out your DNA strand bases E.g. A T C G C A T G");
            input1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(InputBaseWithSpaces());
            Console.WriteLine(OpposingBases());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Go character by character and swap depending on the desired output heh

Comment: Because, if I were to keep doing `outputBases2 = input1.Replace("T", "A");`, etc, I can only return one of them

Comment: You can use a temporary substitute, ie: T->x, A->T, x->A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to a char array and replace in place

```
string  input = "ATCG";
//TAGC

char[] inputChar = input.ToCharArray();

for(int i=0;i< inputChar.Length; i++)
{
    switch(inputChar[i])
    {
        case 'A':
            inputChar[i]='T';
            break;
        case 'T':
            inputChar[i]='A';
            break;
        case 'G':
            inputChar[i]='C';
            break;
        case 'C':
            inputChar[i]='G';
            break;
    }
}
var output =new string(inputChar);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `Regex.Replace` to replace string based on a dictionary (map):

```
Dictionary<string, string> complementary = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
    { "A", "T" },
    { "T", "A" },
    { "C", "G" },
    { "G", "C" }

};
string input = "ATCG";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[ATCG]", match => complementary[match.Value]);
```

this replaces any of the "ATCG" character match with corresponding value from dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this worked. I didn't just want the string "ATCG" to be replaced with "TAGC". I wanted it to work with any string, the letters are just replaced. When I entered `ATTGCC` it just returned "TAGC"

Comment: If I replace input with `ATTGCC`, it returns `TAACGG` for me.. But remember to leave `[ATCG]` parameter untouched, it is pattern for regex.

Comment: This is answer (as well as my own) are both better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
string MakeOpposite(string sourceString) {
    var opposites = new Dictionary<char, char> {
        { 'A', 'T' },
        { 'T', 'A' },
        { 'G', 'C' },
        { 'C', 'G' }
    };
    var oppositeString = new string(sourceString.Select(x => opposites[x]));
    return oppositeString;
}
```

Comment: Your typing speed is much faster than me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a foreach and switch statement over your Char Array to replace each letter.

```
foreach (char base in strand)
{
    switch (base.ToString())
    {
        case "g":
            //replace code
            break;
        case "c":
            //replace code
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `base` is a keyword in C#, so I'm pretty sure this would not compile without changing it to `@base`. This also has the same issue with `string`s in the cases instead of `char`s, like another answer had.

Answer (score 1):

You should instead write a routine to go through character by character and do the replacement (don't use the string.replace method).

```
private string ConvertDNA(string original)
{
        StringBuilder newone = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(char c in original)
        {
            switch(c)
            {
                case 'A':
                    newone.Append('T');
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    newone.Append('A');
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    newone.Append('G');
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    newone.Append('C');
                    break;
                default:
                    newone.Append(c);
                    break;
            }       
        }
        return newone.ToString();
}
```

Note that if your original string is certain forms of Unicode, this could do funny things.   You should use stringbuilder rather than the += syntax in the other answers because its more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using a Switch statement

```
public static string OpposingBases()
    {
        string outputBases1;
        foreach(var s in input1)
        {            
          switch (s)
          {
            case "A":
              outputBases1 +="T";
              break;
            case "T":
              outputBases1 +="A";
              break;
            case "C":
              outputBases1 +="G";
              break;
            case "G":
              outputBases1 +="C";
              break;
            case " ":
              outputBases1 +=" ";
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
         }
        return outputBases1;
    }
```

Comment: This returns `cannot implicitly convert type string to char` on each of the cases, like "A"

Comment: @DunderMifflin11 if the double quotation marks were changed to singe quotation marks in the case statements, this would fix the error "cannot implicitly convert type string to char".  e.g. `case 'A':`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, but you can do better:

```
code = code.Replace("A","x").Replace("C","y").Replace("T","A").Replace("G","C").Replace("x","T").Replace("y","G");
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, surely it'd work cumulatively, changing each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
    public static string OpposingBases()
    {
        var baseDictionary = new Dictionary<char, char>()
        {
            {'A', 'T'},
            {'T', 'A'},
            {'C', 'G'},
            {'G', 'C'}
        };
        return input1.Where(baseDictionary.ContainsKey).Aggregate("", (current, c) => current + baseDictionary[c]);
    }
```